# assign flexbox cells the same width

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am building a table using display flex inside bootstrap 4 framework.

My goal is to have a table where the first column will always be the same and the other columns will be updated massively with an ajax call. That's why I am keeping two outer columns: one with the fixed column and one that contains the others. This approach has an issue: the columns on the right don't have the same width. **How do I assign each the same width?** I want to keep the right part as rows since I will fetch the data row by row on the backend to update this table.
Note: I started to build the structure from [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#wrap)

```css
.cell {
  border 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="p-2 cell">Header</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">101</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">102</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">103</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">104</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">105</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">106</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">107</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">108</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="p-2 cell">1</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">2</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">3</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">4</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">5</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">6</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">7</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">8</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">9</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">10</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">11</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">12</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">13</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">14</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">15</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.1</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.2</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.3</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.4</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.5</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.6</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.7</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.8</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.9</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.10</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.11</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.12</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.13</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.14</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.15</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.1</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.2</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.3</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.4</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.5</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.6</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.7</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.8</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.9</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.10</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.11</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.12</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.13</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.14</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.15</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're building a `table`, why are you using divs?

Comment: because this is not a table. I am not displaying tabular data. table is only for tabular data representation. Also with a table it will be a nightmare to update only some columns all togheter, this layout is way simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `justify-content-around` class to each row

```css
.cell {
  border 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="p-2 cell">Header</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">101</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">102</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">103</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">104</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">105</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">106</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">107</div>
      <div class="p-2 cell">108</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
        <div class="p-2 cell">1</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">2</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">3</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">4</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">5</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">6</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">7</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">8</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">9</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">10</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">11</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">12</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">13</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">14</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">15</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.1</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.2</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.3</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.4</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.5</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.6</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.7</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.8</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.9</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.10</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.11</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.12</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.13</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.14</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">101.15</div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.1</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.2</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.3</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.4</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.5</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.6</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.7</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.8</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.9</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.10</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.11</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.12</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.13</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.14</div>
        <div class="p-2 cell">102.15</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: almost there! how to tell this structure to take 100% of the width of parent div?

Comment: give width as 100% and give text alignment if you want. 
`.cell {width: 100%;
    text-align: center;}`